# Prestashop product admin hooks

Tags: output, prestashop, hook

I am creating a new plugin for Prestashop. Plugin is activated, working fine except, that I am not able to hook into a specific area in the Prestashop Product Admin (backoffice).

I am using this hook: DisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle.
I can see that it is placed in the prestashop's templating twig engine, and I am using it like below, but content is simply not showing.

Odd thing is that, I can easily hook into i.e. Hook AdminOrder, no problem, but not DisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle.

```
class my_module extends Module
{


    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->name = "my_module";
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'my_author';
        $this->need_instance = 1;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.6',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_,
        ];

        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('my_module');
        $this->description = $this->l('my_module');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('You are about to uninstall Product addons. Wish to continue?');

    }

    public function install()
    {
        return
            parent::install()
            && $this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle')
            && $this->registerHook('adminOrder');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    public function HookDisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle() //No content is being displayed in the productpage backoffice
    {
        echo 'Content in hook';
    }

    public function HookAdminOrder() //This hook works perfectly fine
    {
        echo 'Content in hook';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `return` instead of `echo` and it will work

```
public function hookDisplayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle()
{
    return 'Content in hook';
}
```

and do not forget to reset your module to register the hook at first

Comment: No difference, still no content :/

Comment: Where do you expect it to show up? And what version of Prestashop do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that it is explicit to register hooks (especially for backend hooks) in the install function. I just registered the hook in the constructor for testing purposes (frontend hooks always worked for me that way).

So I put the hook inside installer function, reactivated the module and then it worked.

Hope this can help someone =)